# Running `cabal haddock` on a repo with plutus code errors

Tags: plutus-pioneer-program, documentation

Aim: document a repo with plutus code using haddock.

Problem: Naively running `cabal haddock` has a problem that seems to be caused by plutus (on-chain) code.

For example, plutus-pioneer-program [week03](https://github.com/input-output-hk/plutus-pioneer-program/tree/main/code/week03) runs in the repl with `cabal repl`, but `cabal haddock` errors as follows.

```
Haddock coverage:
GHC Core to PLC plugin: E043:Error: Reference to a name which is not a local, a builtin, or an external INLINABLE function: Variable Ledger.Typed.Scripts.Validators.wrapValidator
            No unfolding
Context: Compiling expr: Ledger.Typed.Scripts.Validators.wrapValidator
Context: Compiling expr: Ledger.Typed.Scripts.Validators.wrapValidator
                           @ Week03.Homework1.VestingDatum
Context: Compiling expr: Ledger.Typed.Scripts.Validators.wrapValidator
                           @ Week03.Homework1.VestingDatum @ ()
Context: Compiling expr: Ledger.Typed.Scripts.Validators.wrapValidator
                           @ Week03.Homework1.VestingDatum
                           @ ()
                           Week03.Homework1.$fUnsafeFromDataVestingDatum
Context: Compiling expr: Ledger.Typed.Scripts.Validators.wrapValidator
                           @ Week03.Homework1.VestingDatum
                           @ ()
                           Week03.Homework1.$fUnsafeFromDataVestingDatum
                           PlutusTx.IsData.Instances.$fUnsafeFromData()
Context: Compiling expr at "plutus-pioneer-program-week03-0.1.0.0-inplace:Week03.Homework1:(60,8)-(60,37)"
cabal: Failed to build documentation for
plutus-pioneer-program-week03-0.1.0.0.
```

Is there a straightforward way to build haddock docs for repos with plutus code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes! Try `cabal haddock -fplugin-opt Plutus.Tx.Plugin:defer-errors`.

(From https://plutus-apps.readthedocs.io/en/latest/plutus/troubleshooting.html#plugin-errors)

Comment: Editing the `cabal.project` file as the link suggests gets `cabal haddock` working so I'm good. Passing cli arguments as suggested above or in the docs linked gives an error: `cabal: Unrecognised target 'PlutusTx.Plugin:defer-errors'.
Expected a module name, rather than 'defer-errors'.`
I tried various perturbations such as `Plutus.Tx...`